# Is there a RAW way to pick an ally up from Prone?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, actions, prone

If an ally is Prone (woke up from sleep, tripped, etc...) is there a RAW way to 'pick them up' so they don't have to use their own Move action to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no explicit RAW method to lift someone up who is prone.

As usual with these kind of answers, it is difficult to prove that no book out there includes this as a combat action. Our best bet is to look at a rules aggregator (d20pfsrd) and take a look at the applicable section. The [Actions in Combat section](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat#TOC-Actions-In-Combat) of the Combat page includes a list of actions players can take.

While the section does not explicitly mention picking up a prone character, the following action may apply depending on DM interpretation:

> Move a Heavy Object (Move Action) (AoO = Yes)

Comment: About what I expected. Good thought on using the move an object though.